# Is there an API in IOBluetooth (OSX) to set the host controller address?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I have searched the [IOBluetooth API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/Reference/IOBluetooth/_index.html) but I couldn't find a way to set the address of the host controller. Is it possible through this API? If not, is there another workaround?